# Combine active_record models and sort by shared properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm displaying Authors on a page (Rails view) like so:

`Author.where(featured: true).where.not(username: nil).order(:priority, :name)`

However I have recently added a new model `Photographer` and I would like to combine the photographers with the authors and sort them similarly. They share most of the same columns.

I've tried:

```
combined = (Author.where(featured: true).where.not(username: nil) + Photographer.where(featured: true).where.not(username: nil))

combined.order(:priority, name)
=> NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x00005573bc2ab3b0>)

combined.sort_by {|item| [item.priority, item.name]}
=> ArgumentError (comparison of Array with Array failed)
```

One caveat is that in some cases `priority` would be `nil`. So in that event it should order by name instead.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `nil` is only comparable with `nil`:

```rb
       nil <=> nil  # => 0         # -1, 0, 1 are good
"priority" <=> nil  # => nil       # `nil` means not comparable 
                                   # and you get an error from `sort_by`
```

Solution is to avoid comparing `nil` with anything else or explicitly handle the comparison.

You can use `sort` and sort the `nil`s yourself:

```rb
ary = (Author.all + Photographer.all)

ary.sort do |a, b|
  if a.priority && b.priority              # priority <=> priority
    a.priority <=> b.priority
  elsif a.priority                         # priority <=> nil
    -1                # nil is lower 
  elsif b.priority                         #      nil <=> priority
    1                 # priority is higher
  else                                     #      nil <=> nil
    a.name <=> b.name # break the tie
  end
end
```

You can split array in two, with priority and without priority, and sort each one. That way `priority` is compared to `priority`; `nil` is compared to `nil`, which is 0, and it falls back to comparing `name` (like the `sort` above, but *elsif'*s never match):

```rb
ary.partition(&:priority).flat_map do |part|
  part.sort_by { |i| [i.priority, i.name] }
end
```

Or a dumber way of doing this (it's also faster) is to make `nil` be something last:

```rb
ary.sort_by { |i| [i.priority||"zzz", i.name] }
```

Comment: This was an excellent answer and helped me understand the issue. The first two solutions worked, however when I attempted the third, I was met with the error: `comparison of Array with Array failed`.

Comment: @dedles in general, you have to compare the same class of an object: `nil <=> nil`, `1 <=> 2`, `"a" <=> "9"`. Things like this don't compare: `1 <=> "2"`, `"a" <=> :a`, `false <=> true`. I assumed `priority` is a string, but, if it is something else, like an Integer, then "zzz" needs to be changed to match the class.

Comment: Of course. Yes it is an integer.