# How to Sort Method to Force an Element to the Front of the Array

Tags: ruby

I want sort an array of String by alphabet but force one to the front of the array

```
p ['Home', 'Contact', 'Profile', 'Jobs', 'Privacy'].sort { |x, y|
  if x == 'Privacy'
    -1
  else
    x <=> y
  end
}
```

Gives me ["Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Privacy", "Profolio"]

instead of ["Privacy", "Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Profolio"]

Eventually I want to sort an array of objects by name attribute

```
class Page
  include Comparable

  def <=> (other)
    if self.name == 'Jobs'
       -1
    else
      self.name <=> other.name
    end
  end
end

[Page.new('Contact'), Page.new('Home'), Page.new('Jobs')...].sort
```

However overwriting <=> in the Comparable class doesn't work as well

Comment: You need `def initialize(name); @name = name; end` and `attr_reader :name` and then `if case name == 'Privacy'; -1; else other == 'Privacy' ? 1 : name <=> other; end`..

Comment: For your `Page` class, you could introduce a `level` attribute which defaults to `0`. Sorting can then be done via `def <=> (other); [self.level, self.name] <=> [other.level, other.name] ; end` – levels appear in ascending order and pages with identical level are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the sort for both `x` and `y`:

```rb
["Home", "Contact", "Profile", "Jobs", "Privacy"].sort { |x, y|
  if x == "Privacy"          # "Privacy" <=> y
    -1                       # y is lower
  elsif y == "Privacy"       # x <=> "Privacy"
    1                        # "Privacy" is higher
  else                       # the rest
    x <=> y                  # use default sort order
  end
}
# => ["Privacy", "Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Profile"]
```

Same thing when using `Comparable`:

```rb
class Page
  include Comparable

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end

  def <=> other
    if @name == "Privacy"
      -1
    elsif other == "Privacy"
      1
    else
      @name <=> other
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
>> [Page.new("Contact"), Page.new("Home"), Page.new("Jobs"), Page.new("Privacy")].sort
=> [#<Page:0x00007f8688624d30 @name="Privacy">, #<Page:0x00007f8688624ec0 @name="Contact">, #<Page:0x00007f8688624e20 @name="Home">, #<Page:0x00007f8688624da8 @name="Jobs">]
```

---

One other way I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73216544/207090):

```rb
>> ["Home", "Contact", "Profile", "Jobs", "Privacy"]
     .partition{|i| i == "Privacy"}
     .flat_map(&:sort)
=> ["Privacy", "Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Profile"]
```

---

Ok, I was just wondering:

```rb
require "benchmark"

a = (1..100_000).map{ rand(36**8).to_s(36) } + ["privacy"]
d = a.dup # because `.delete` modifies the array

Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
   b.report("Delete Sort")    { [d.delete("privacy"), *d.sort] }
   b.report("Partition Sort") { a.partition{|i| i == "privacy"}.flat_map(&:sort) }
   b.report("Sort by String") { a.sort_by {|i| i == "privacy" ? "" : i } }
   b.report("Sort")           { a.sort {|x, y| if x == "privacy";-1; elsif y == "privacy";1; else x<=>y end } }
   b.report("Sort by Array")  { a.sort_by {|s| s == "privacy" ? [0, ""] : [1, s] } }
end

                      user     system      total        real
Delete Sort       0.035848   0.000000   0.035848 (  0.035891)
Partition Sort    0.045608   0.000044   0.045652 (  0.045711)
Sort by String    0.068656   0.000018   0.068674 (  0.068733)
Sort              0.307052   0.000000   0.307052 (  0.307237)
Sort by Array     0.493351   0.000000   0.493351 (  0.493606) # making arrays is expensive
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following.

```
arr = ['Home', 'Contact', 'Profile', 'Jobs', 'Privacy']
```

```
arr.sort_by { |s| s == 'Privacy' ? [0, ''] : [1, s] }
  #=> ["Privacy", "Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Profile"].
```

[Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to order arrays. See especially the third paragraph of the latter doc.

Note that the second element of `[0, '']` is arbitrary. That's because it is never referenced by `sort_by`. For example, `[0, { a:1, b:2 }]` or `[0]` would work as well.

It's probably faster to use `sort_by` than `sort` because `sort_by` computes a two-element array for each element of the array only once, whereas `sort` performs a comparable calculation twice for each pairwise ordering it considers.

---

Better, in a comment @Alex suggested:

```
arr.sort_by { |s| s == "Privacy" ? "" : s }
```

---

Alternatively, you could write:

```
a = arr.sort
[a.delete('Privacy'), *a]
  #=> ["Privacy", "Contact", "Home", "Jobs", "Profile"]
```

Comment: `arr.sort_by { |s| s == "Privacy" ? "" : s }` could also work

Comment: Hi Cary, I don't follow the block `[0, ''] : [1, s]`, e.g.  how does the comparison works when the block returns `[1, s]`? Thanks

Comment: @Alex, that's lovely! How about `arr.sort_by { |s| s == "Privacy" ? "\x00Hey, diddle, diddle" : s }`?

Comment: user1883793, let's suppose `sort_by` is comparing `a0 = [1, "Jobs"]` with `a1 = [1, "Home"]`. It first compares `a0[0]` with `a1[0]` and finds they are equal (both `1`). To break the tie it then compares `a0[1]` with `a1[1]`, or `"Jobs"` with `"Home"` and finds that `a0[1] <=> a1[1] #=> 1`, meaning that `a0 <=> a1 #=> 1`. On the other hand, if it compares `a0 = [0, '']` with, say `[1, "Jobs"]`, it will find that  `a0[0] <=> a1[0] #=> -1` so `a0 <=> a1 #=> -1`. In this case it will not examine the second element of each array.

Comment: An alternate to your alternate would be `a.unshift(a.delete("Privacy"))` avoids the extra Array.